Excel IFS function
I use Excel IFS function to add *
The working function is:
=IF(G5="","",FIXED(G5,1)&IFS(ABS(G6)>=2.575,"***",ABS(G6)>=1.96,"**",ABS(G6)>=1.645,"*",ABS(G6)<1.645,""))

Since I see ABS(G6)<1.645 is redundant so I decided to drop it
=IF(G5="","",FIXED(G5,1)&IFS(ABS(G6)>=2.575,"***",ABS(G6)>=1.96,"**",ABS(G6)>=1.645,"*"))

But the formula run into issue return #N/A
I hope someone can explain for me why removing part cause the issue?

You need to provide the "else" branch for IFS:
=IF(G5="",
  "",
  FIXED(G5,1)&IFS(
    ABS(G6)>=2.575,"***",
    ABS(G6)>=1.96,"**",
    ABS(G6)>=1.645,"*",
    TRUE,""
  )
)

Read Remarks in IFS function:
To specify a default result, enter TRUE for your final logical_test argument. If none of the other conditions are met, the corresponding value will be returned.

If a logical_test argument is supplied without a corresponding value_if_true, this function shows a "You've entered too few arguments for this function" error message.
If a logical_test argument is evaluated and resolves to a value other than TRUE or FALSE, this function returns a '#VALUE!' error.
If no TRUE conditions are found, this function returns '#N/A' error.

So, you've got '#N/A' due to ABS(G6)<1.645 and there is no such condition in the list.
Also, you can suppress '#N/A' by another way:
=IF(G5="",
  "",
  FIXED(G5,1)&IFNA(
    IFS(
      ABS(G6)>=2.575,"***",
      ABS(G6)>=1.96,"**",
      ABS(G6)>=1.645,"*"
    ),
    ""
  )
)


Your first formula is complete, whereas the second one isn't.  The IFS function needs to cover every possible situation, so in the second formula, it doesn't know what to do when the G6 value is less than 1.65. The documentation on IFS states that you can use an ELSE clause to handle any value not covered by the specified ranges.  Check out this link:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-ifs-function/
